# Airflow on Kubernetes: Pods are able to run initdb over PostgreSql, but subsequent create_user targets SQLite

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I'm setting up Apache Airflow in Kubernetes using a Helm Chart in a local Kubernetes cluster, provided as part of Docker Desktop.

In the Helm chart, I have:

- Requirements.yaml -> PostgreSql (Bitnami Helm Chart)
- Deployments-Web.yaml -> Airflow Webserver
- Deployments-Scheduler.yaml -> Airflow Scheduler
- Jobs.yaml -> Provisioning job to run airflow initdb, create_user etc.

[image]

The pods for Webserver and Scheduler are able to successfully connect to the Pod running PostgreSql. But the Batch job defined in Jobs.yaml gets "Connection refused".

- The SQLAlchemy connection string is the same for all pods
- If I move the arguments from Jobs.yaml to an arbitrary, third
  deployment, it works - I'm able to connect to the Pod running PostgreSql. But since I want to run this only once, I would like to keep it as a job.

*Error on provisioner pod* :

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "orchestrator-postgresql" (10.105.92.200) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

`kubectl describe pod` for the failing pod gives:

```
Name:         orchestrator-provisioner-9d77p Namespace:    orchestrator Priority:     0 Node:         docker-desktop/192.168.65.3 Start Time:   Thu, 03 Sep 2020 15:04:56 +0200 Labels:       controller-uid=09661ecd-f8da-4c76-9c9b-4d2e80cf8253
              job-name=orchestrator-provisioner Annotations:  <none> Status:       Failed IP:           10.1.0.221 IPs:   IP:          
10.1.0.221 Controlled By:  Job/orchestrator-provisioner Containers:   provisioner:
    Container ID:  docker://eeee02787b323f2991d91347b1ae306a7d0c4935fa49ee738fc91c64b020f18e
    Image:         xxx
    Image ID:      docker://sha256:d2ebf8eefd15abe77b979bb281820c6f7c3a073e16716ad5c3b51b660e140081
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      airflow initdb;
      sleep 10;
      airflow create_user \
      --role Admin \
      --username airflow \
      --password airflow \
      --firstname Air \
      --lastname Flow \
      --email air.flow@examle.com;
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Thu, 03 Sep 2020 15:04:56 +0200
      Finished:     Thu, 03 Sep 2020 15:05:16 +0200
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment Variables from:
      orchestrator-secrets  Secret     Optional: false
      orchestrator-env      ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:
      AIRFLOW_KUBE_NAMESPACE:  orchestrator
    Mounts:
      /usr/local/airflow/airflow.cfg from airflow-config (rw,path="airflow.cfg")
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-glzmg (ro) Conditions:   Type              Status   Initialized       True    Ready             False    ContainersReady   False    PodScheduled      True  Volumes:   airflow-config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      orchestrator-config
    Optional:  false   default-token-glzmg:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-glzmg
    Optional:    false QoS Class:       BestEffort Node-Selectors:  <none> Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s 
    Events:
```

Any hints on what could be wrong?

**EDIT**: found what the issue was. In the first time the Batch Job tries to run, PostgreSql Pod is up, but the service is not. So the port is still not open which causes Connection Refused. In the second time that the Batch Job runs, it is successful in initializing the metadata DB in PostgreSql.

However now I'm facing another issue. After *initdb*, I'm running *airflow create_user*. For some reason, this one fails to pick up the environment variables containing the SQLAlchemy connection string, and keep trying to create a user in a SQLite DB instead.

Comment: All are in same namespace?

Comment: Yes, same namespace

Comment: Added screenshot showing all pods from the namespace

Comment: Do you have a `Service` named `orchestrator-postgresql` in the `orchestrator` namespace ? What is the output of `kubectl get svc -n orchestrator` command ?

Comment: what I did and works is using a init-container inside webserver yaml as deployment. Are you trying the similar way.

Comment: @mario yes, when I run kubectl get svc -n orchestrator I can see orchestrator-postgresql

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon nice one. Think will give a try over an initContainer instead of a batch job. Will let you know if it works

Comment: after doing some more investigation I think I found the issue with initdb: when the batch job tries to run it, the PostgreSql pod is up, but the service is not. That's why I get connection refused. In the second time the batch job runs, it is able to initialize the DB.

Comment: But then, on the subsequent command (airflow create_user) it does not pick up the SQLAlchemy connection string and tries to create the user on a SQLite DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for those who come by this question - I ended up giving up on my initial approach (Kubernetes Batch Job for initializing Airflow DB and users) and instead I cloned the official [Airflow Helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/airflow) and made some changes.